# Align android layout with equal margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am adding a footer to my app which will contain three buttons with image. I want similar to below view. I have tried `android:layout_gravity="right/left/center"` but seems not working.

[image]

Below is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!-- Root element should wrap to parent size. -->

<!-- Your view xml codes. -->

<!--Bottom bar layout should be in root element. Parent should be Relative layout so that we can always align to parent bottom-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="4">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/brands"

        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"

        />


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >


    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/stores"

        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"

        />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    >


    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/coupons"

        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"

        />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parent `LinearLayout`have `android:weightSum="4"` and your child `LinearLayout` all sum is 3.

so change your parent `LinearLayout` weightSum `android:weightSum="4"` to `android:weightSum="3"`.

**Update :**

add this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!-- Root element should wrap to parent size. -->

<!-- Your view xml codes. -->

<!--Bottom bar layout should be in root element. Parent should be Relative layout so that we can always align to parent bottom-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/brands"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/stores"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/coupons"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It did make all the image equally fit  the screen. But I wanted something like the picture iv posted . three images with equal margin.  .

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/brands"
/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="brands"
/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shops"
/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="shops"
/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/coupons"
/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="coupons"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try Something like this,

```
LinearLayout(Horizontal)
  - LinearLayout(Vertical)
        - ImageView (for the image)
        - Textview (for title)
  - LinearLayout(Vertical)
        - ImageView (for the image)
        - Textview (for title)
  - LinearLayout(Vertical)
        - ImageView (for the image)
        - Textview (for title)
```

Comment: Yes it is actually arranging three layouts with equal space, thus getting too big Images. but I exactly want something like the picture Iv posted. With margins.

Comment: I would recommend keeping your image views width to something like 24dp...and if you have images in a svg form use vector drawables to display them

Comment: I added android:layout_margin="10dp" and layout_width="24dp" but now the image view height i too large. Don't know why

Comment: width and height both should be 24dp. here's the android bottom navigation guidelines doc, you can read more about the margins and size you can use on a layout like this https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/brands" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="brands" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/stores" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stores" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/coupons" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Coupons" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pro tips for posting here: readers prefer real words rather than abbreviated "txtspk" - the latter is fine for Facebook chat, but we'd rather keep things more readable here. We're keen for paragraph text not to be merged with code formatting too, again to make things as clear as possible. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Root element should wrap to parent size. -->

<!-- Your view xml codes. -->

<!--Bottom bar layout should be in root element. Parent should be Relative layout so that we can always align to parent bottom-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/brands" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="brands" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/stores" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="brands" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/coupons" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="brands" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Yes. Besides Ive added 
                android:layout_width="63dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"

Answer (score 1):

Give equal weight to layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

change all inner layouts

> android:layout_gravity="left"
>
> ```
> android:layout_margin="10dp"//as required
> ```

and change

> android:weightSum="3"

in parent layout